# ggmap - stat_binhex and scale_fill_gradientn limits

Tags: ggmap

I use ggmap and stat_binhex to visualize the density of the boat in a given area. I don't want to display all the positions, only the ones where I really have a high density of positions.

[image]

So I use "scale_fill_gradientn" with the limits parameter to filter all the hexagon that have less than 500 positions. The limit parameter needs to specify the lowest and the highest value. While it's fine for the lowest value, I don't want to manually specify the highest value (currently 100000) but instead get it from the "stat_binhex" result. Do you know if it's possible and how I can do that ?

Here is my current code :

```
 ggmap(map, extent = "panel", maprange=FALSE) + 
   coord_cartesian() +
   theme(legend.position='none') +
   geom_point(data=positions, aes(x=positions$x, y=positions$y), alpha=0.1, size=0.01, color="grey") +
   stat_binhex(data=positions, aes(x,y), binwidth=c(0.05, 0.05)) +
   scale_fill_gradientn( colours= brewer.pal( 6, "YlGn"), 
          na.value = NA, trans= "log10", limits=c(500,100000))
```

Thanks for your help

Arnaud

Comment: Will you be able to provide a minimal data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help page `?scale_fill_gradientn` points to `?continuous_scale` which states that you can use `NA` (or `NA_real_`) for the limit you don't want to set manually. With a dummy data set:

[image: high density bins visualized]

Here is the complete code:

```
library(ggmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
left <-   -4.8
bottom <- 45.8
right <-  -1.2
top <-    48.2
map <- get_stamenmap(c(left, bottom, right, top),
                     maptype = "toner", zoom = 8)
positions <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5e5, mean = -4, sd = 0.5),
                        y = rnorm(5e5, mean = 46.5, sd = 0.3))
positions <- positions[with(positions, x > left & x < right &
                                       y > bottom & y < top), ]

print(ggmap(map, extent = "panel", maprange=FALSE) + 
    coord_cartesian() +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    geom_point(data=positions, aes(x, y), alpha=0.1, size=0.01,
               color="grey") +
    stat_binhex(data=positions, aes(x, y), binwidth=c(0.05, 0.05)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal( 6, "YlGn"), 
                         na.value = NA, trans= "log10", limits = c(500, NA)))
```